# Programmatically Change Drawable file radius android

Tags: java, android

**windows_backgraound.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:bottom="-14.5dp"
        android:left="-15dp"
        android:right="-14.9dp"
        android:top="-15.1dp"
        android:id="@+id/my_shape">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="15dp"
                android:color="#000000" />
            <corners android:radius="40dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And **MyWindowManagerService.java**

```
ImageView mView = new ImageView(this);

mView .setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.windows_backgraound));

        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FIRST_SYSTEM_WINDOW,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        wm.addView(mView, params);
```

My problem is that I would like to change the drawable resource radius  programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the solution

```
  float[] statusRadii = new float[]{12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12}; // For Corners
  GradientDrawable approvedStatusBg = new GradientDrawable();
        approvedStatusBg.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
        approvedStatusBg.setCornerRadii(statusRadii);
        approvedStatusBg.setColor(Color.parseColor("#66BB6A"));
```